# Efficient/Secure Method to Handle Temporary JSON Data Processing with User-Created Queries

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql, lodash

I'm working on a project where I need to process temporary JSON data based on user-generated queries, and I'm looking for advice on an efficient and secure method to implement this.

Context:
Goal: Allow users to submit queries that temporarily process JSON data. I retrieve the data from a separate endpoint and want to allow the user to manipulate it. Ideally, I'd accept a json query like mongo and execute it in memory against the json response from my other endpoint. I do not have any restrictions on language or tools to use.

Security Concern: I want to avoid the risks associated with SQL injection and ensure that users can only access and manipulate their session-specific data. Hence I think its risky to dump data directly into mongo and query against it if I have concurrent requests.

Considered Approaches:

- Databases: I considered using MongoDB with user-specific collections and PostgreSQL with temporary tables, creating a new user with restricted permissions for each session. However, I'm concerned about the scalability and performance of these approaches.
- In memory: I considered using a tool like lodash but it doesn't seem to accept json queries so that might be difficult to accept a users query.
- I considered using a more graphql like approach where I would accept a users request in a graphql format and query against the json. However, this is limited in that it could restrict fields but I'd also like access to more advanced query options like aggregating results.

---

Ultimately I'm curious if anyone has and ideas on how this could best be handled. Any tools or alternative approaches to handle this problem that I haven't considered.

Comment: It's a bit contradicting if you say "want to allow the user to manipulate it" or "accept any json query" and at the same time you are concerned about SQL injection. I cannot have both at the same time. Most important point is, grant privileges least as possible to the user.

Comment: Right, and maybe sql injection isn't the right way to put it. What I really want is a sandbox where the user can manipulate the json however they want without touching the server or other user data.